# How to read large excel file in asp.net c# by splitting it into simpler?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to read large excel file in asp.net c#? Actually i have a excel file with 10000 rows i have to read each 100 rows and process that rows is it possible in asp.net c#? i am planning to do it in a thread.

Comment: Please, try to add some code, and write what you have tried so far. It will help the community, and you will show that you actually spend some time to solve it.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Hint: Save as CSV format and use a File.ReadLines() to stream it, (instead of reading the whole file into memory)